# Identification help

Tags: character-identification

I'd like to know if this is Chinese and if so what do these marks mean/say?
This vase was my grandmother's and I don't care about monetary value but I have always loved to know about the history of pieces.
Any help or direction is appreciated and thanks in advance![image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The character on top of the picture is 四 (four).
The words on the center is [香山](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A6%99%E5%B1%B1_(%E5%8C%97%E4%BA%AC))造 (made in Xiangshan)

Comment: Thank you so much!